# dovecot+roundcube (different IP)

Tags: dovecot, roundcube

How to set dovecot to allow plain auth for some IP? I have lxc-containers - one with roundcube, and one with dovecot. Because the ip are different disable_plaintext_auth = yes disallows plain connection from roundcube. I can't use ssl || tls because internal IP doesn't match ssl cert CommonName (external IP).

So, do yoy have idea how to enable plain for one ip?

Answer (score 1):

I found the workaround - i'm not happy with this, but - works. I add external domain to /etc/hosts (external domain points to internal dovecot ip). So now ssl cert matches the request - so it works . It of course works worse than plain - but works. If someone will find better solution - i'd be happy.